# How to toggle a .on("click") function

Tags: javascript, jquery

See below code. When clicked this makes the text Bold. I would like to be able to toggle between 'normal' and 'bold' text by clicking the same button. How could I achieve this?

```
$("#InputsWrapper").on("click", ".boldText", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find(".fTypex").css({"font-weight":"bold"});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better approach would be to toggle the class with [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

*CSS:*

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$('#InputsWrapper').on('click', '.boldText', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find('.fTypex').toggleClass('bold');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bz9wnh6m/

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="boldtrigger">Bold</a>
<div class="text"> Here is the text </div>
```

JS:

```
$(".boldtrigger").click(function() {
    $(".text").toggleClass("bold");
});
```

Here's a working example for JQUERY 2.0+ using the toggleClass() method: http://jsfiddle.net/S9qDD/

Cheers!

Comment: The `toggle` event was deprecated and completely removed from the recent versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is the .toggleClass() method.
here is a [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

and a example

```
<script>
 $("#InputsWrapper").on("click", ".boldText", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().find(".fTypex").toggleClass("bold-text");
});
</script>
<style>
 .bold-text{
     font-weight":"bold;
 }
</style>
```